# Different output when comparing dates with timezone when using psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

A simple query

```
SELECT current_date = current_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

returns `TRUE`,

but if I run the same script through python psycopg2 returns `FALSE`.

```
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT current_date = current_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'")
c.fetchone()
(False,)
```

As you can imagine went mad debugging my software.

and then I did this

```
c.execute("SELECT current_date = (current_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata')::date")
c.fetchone()
(True,)
```

Voila `TRUE`

so when querying through python psycopg2 we must cast the date `at timezone 'Asia/Kolkata'` to data type `date`. Though the behaviour is consistent when using `timezone 'UTC'` ie the output is same in psql and python psycopg2 for `at timezone 'UTC'`

Is this a flaw in psycopg2 or is it something else which I am missing.

Comment: `<some_date> at time zone :some_tz` is going to turn a `date` into a `timestamp`. So here(US/Pacific): `select current_date at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata';` becomes `02/24/2023 13:30:00`. Best bet is you are dealing with time zone differences. So it is not a flaw you are mixing data types in your comparison.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My concern is in the different answer provided by psycopg2. Same query is giving different outputs.